# Angular + Ol map problem with undefined coords outside function

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers

I am building an Angular app which manages apartments, I am using ol map. I want to store the longitude and latitude every time the user clicks on the map. Inside the on.click function the coords are displayed ok in the console. However when I try to access them in other functions they appear to be undefined.

Here is my code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { AppartmentService } from '../appartment.service';
import { appartment } from '../models/appartment';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import{User} from 'src/app/models/User';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

declare var ol: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-appartment',
  templateUrl: './add-appartment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-appartment.component.css']
})

export class AddAppartmentComponent implements OnInit {
  map: any;
  lon;
  lat;
  tempApp:appartment;
  endD:String="";
  startD:String="";
  country:String="";
  city:String="";
  appartmentTypes:String[]=["private flat","shared room","full house"];
  hood:String="";
  dates: String[];
  curentUser:User;
  psw:String;
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public selectedFile;
  public event1;
  imgURL: any;
  receivedImageData: any;
  coords:any;
  base64Data: any;
  convertedImage: any;
  formatDate(inputDate:String){
    let Arr=inputDate.split("-");
    console.log(Arr[2])
    let day=Arr[2];
    let month=Arr[1];
    let year=Arr[0];
    var result:String;
    if(day.charAt(0)=='0')
      result=day.charAt(1).toString();
    else
      result=day
    result=result+"-";
    if(month.charAt(0)=='0')
      result+=month.charAt(1).toString();
    else result+=month
  
    result=result+"-"+year;
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,private userHttp:UserService,private appHttp:AppartmentService,private httpClient:HttpClient ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.tempApp=new appartment;
    ///initializing all to false
    this.tempApp.hasTv=this.tempApp.hasWifi=this.tempApp.hasElevator=this.tempApp.hasParking=false;
    this.tempApp.hasheat=this.tempApp.idAvailable=this.tempApp.allowPets=false;
    this.tempApp.allowSmoking=false;
    //this.tempApp.longitude=25;
    //this.tempApp.latitude=25; //random coordinates for a start
    //this.dates=new String[];
    this.set_up_map();
    console.log(this.tempApp.longitude)
    console.log(this.appartmentTypes)
  }
 
  get_dates(startD:string,endD:string):String[]{
    var result:String[]=new Array();
    result.push(startD);
    let sd=+startD.split("-")[0]; 
    let sm=+startD.split("-")[1];
    let sy=+startD.split("-")[2];
    let ed=+endD.split("-")[0];
    let em=+endD.split("-")[1];
    let ey=+endD.split("-")[2];
    for(let day=sd+1;day<=30;day++){
      let temp=day.toString()+"-"+sm.toString()+"-"+sy.toString();
      result.push(temp);  
      if(temp==endD)
        return result;
    }
    for(let year =sy ;year<=ey;year++){
      for(let month=sm+1; month<=em;month++){
        for(let day=1;day<=30;day++){
            let temp=day.toString()+"-"+month.toString()+"-"+year.toString();
            result.push(temp);
            if(temp==endD)
              return result;
        }
      }
    }
    return result;

  }
  PostIt():void{
    //this.tempApp.longitude=this.lon;
    //this.tempApp.latitude=this.lat;
    console.log(this.lon);
    let arr=this.route.snapshot.params.userName.split(":");
    this.tempApp.ownername=arr[1];
    console.log(arr[1]);
    this.userHttp.getUser(arr[1]).subscribe(
      data=>{
        this.curentUser=data;
        this.psw=data.password;}
    );
    var date:String=this.startD;
    this.dates=this.get_dates(this.formatDate(this.startD).toString(),this.formatDate(this.endD).toString());
    console.log(this.dates);
    this.tempApp.dates=this.dates;
    this.appHttp.postAppartment(this.tempApp,this.psw,this.city,this.country,this.hood,this.selectedFile);
  }
  public  onFileChanged(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];

    // Below part is used to display the selected image
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = (event2) => {
      this.imgURL = reader.result;
  };

 }
 set_up_map(){
  console.log(this.tempApp.longitude,this.tempApp.latitude);

  var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
    // be placed within the map.
    //className: 'custom-mouse-position',
   // target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
    undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
  });


  this.map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
      attributionOptions: {
        collapsible: false
      }
    }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([73.8567, 18.5204]),
      zoom: 8
    })
  });

 
  this.map.on('click', function (args) {
    console.log(args.coordinate);
    var lonlat = ol.proj.transform(args.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    console.log(args.coordinate[0]);
    this.lon = args.coordinate[0];
    this.lat = args.coordinate[1];
    console.log(this.lon,this.lat);
    alert(`lat: ${this.lat} long: ${this.lon}`);
  });
}
setCenter() {
  var view = this.map.getView();
  view.setCenter(ol.proj.fromLonLat([this.tempApp.longitude, this.tempApp.latitude]));
  view.setZoom(8);
}
}
```

Comment: i had similar problems, console results are calculated later, which means objects can be null in code and not null in console result, in my situation i was calculating something has that not been completed when i needed in my code but when i checked in console they were completed, so if i want to guess you have concurrency problem (use if to check for actual value, it  it's null then it's null, don't count so much on console result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use arrow function as your click handler. if you dom, the correct `this` will get the fields assigned, and now it is not.

```
 this.map.on('click', (args) => {
```